# Handling unpredictable structure results from mongodb via csharp driver in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I can't retrieve results from MongoDB because I have declared a class that should reflect data structure in the database, but it is not accurate. There is no way for me to be sure how the data is structured (the structure is loose).

Can I somehow override this behavior and return results as they are in the database rather than trying (and failing) to fit the structure into my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I use, it will allow documents with different or missing fields to be parsed. You probably need to do a lot of null checking as you can't expect all fields have content anymore, but that probably goes without saying.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MongoClass
{
...
}
```

Comment: While that's a valid solution it's error-prone. It's safer to use `BsonExtraElements` as Craig Wilson (one of the driver's developers) suggested.

Comment: Thanks I3arnon, but could you explain a bit more? I haven't had any problems with it, but I'm also no pro. Thanks!

Comment: `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` ignores the extra data so you don't know when you're hiding a problem. `BsonExtraElements` would store the extra data in a specific property on your class so you could at least identify when your structure doesn't fit. You can log that info, or even use the actual untyped data.

Comment: Okay, I've red the help file too, but when you're developing your class while the database is running already with test data and you're adding extra fields/properties to your class you'll never find yourself in need to process blind data, you have a lack of data from Mongo. It will always error out because of a mismatch because of missing fields, does BsonExtraElements support that too? I use it because I know some documents have missing fields because it was data from an earlier version of the class with less fields. With IgnoreExraElements my class parses all data, new and old.

Comment: AFAIK, the driver doesn't throw an exception when there's an extra property in your class which isn't in the document.

Comment: About changes, there are many possible ones. You could add properties, remove, change and any extra data will be stored. There are also cases of unstructured data which is inserted by other means to your db.

Comment: I3arnon, I will have a look next time, but we did have problems when we where still extending the class and there was no data for it in the collected BSON document. Thanks for pointing this out. It's definitely a good thing to have a catch for unforeseen/unknown data.

Answer (score 2):

You can either just use a MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, which is essentially just a dictionary, or you can define a class representing the common structure of all your documents, and then use the [BsonExtraElements](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#supporting-extra-elements) attribute to catch all the ones that differ.